# Default Android EditText highlight color not orange

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme

I'm using a EditText on Android 4.1.2 without any style, no attrbiute android:background, nothing. It's a pure EditText created whit Eclipse Layout Editor:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextCommand"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Send"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >
</EditText>
```

But when selected the highlight color is not orange. There is only a little blue line on the bottom of EditText. How can I activate the default orange border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal for the Holo Theme. Change your Theme to `@android:style/Theme` or `Theme.Light` to get that look.